# Printing a PDF File to an Impact Printer Without Font Distortion

Tags: drivers, pdf, printing, fonts, printer

I am working on a project that requires me to use a VB.Net forms application to save a PDF and from there print that file to my impact printer.  That's the easy part.

The printer that I'm using is an Okidata Microline 321 Turbo.  That uses a Generic IBM Graphics 9pin wide driver.

I have been able to print the form, however the font makes the words barely readable.  I've been doing some research and tried changing the Default CPI from 10 to 20 and that did not help. I was wondering if the answer lies within the driver that I'm using.  I've tried several drivers but the Generic IBM driver seems to work the best.

Is there a setting that I would need to change either on the printer or the printer properties to get the font to print more clearly?

[image: Printout]

Also, the font I was using was Arial.  I also ran a test with Courrier New, and that did not help.  Enlarging the font is not an option.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What font? Barely readable how? You’re not giving us much to go on. The obvious response is that you are using a dot matrix printer with a fraction of the resolution and clarity of a modern printer. Is changing or enlarging the font not an option? Take a picture of something.

Answer (score 1):

Start by using the correct driver for your printer. You can download it from the [OKI support website](https://www.oki.com/us/printing/support/drivers-and-utilities/dot-matrix-printers/62411601/). Then make sure you set the printer to its best printing quality, Near Letter Quality (NLQ). This must be done from the driver. A front-panel light will tell you when the printer is using NLQ. You can select NLQ from the front panel, but the driver setting will override that.

In the driver you should be able to tell how to send fonts to the printer. They should be sent as bitmaps. Go to Printer Properties and look through the various tabs and buttons. It should be there somewhere.

Comment: The link for OKI is incorrect.  I have a 321 Turbo.  But, I'll try getting a driver for the 321 Turbo, and run a few tests and will provide an update.  Thank you.

Comment: Sorry about that. Try https://www.oki.com/us/printing/support/drivers-and-utilities/dot-matrix-printers/62411701/

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Comment: Unfortunately, I was not able to get it to work.  I did follow your recommendation to NLQ printing, but sadly it didn't work.  Thank you for your help!